# Implement this OpenGL ES 2.0 code using buffers instead

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, vbo

This code draws a large grid of thousands of coloured squares. On every frame it picks squares at random and sets them to a new colour. I want to reduce CPU load. What would be the ideal code to set up buffers and draw? I'm interested in the VBO setup and Open GL drawing calls only. Bear in mind that the vertex colours in GPU memory are always changing but the vertex positions never change.

```
- (id)initWithBounds:(float)pLeft right:(float)pRight bottom:(float)pBottom top:(float)pTop
{
    if (self = [super init]) {

        effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
        effect.transform.projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(pLeft, pRight, pBottom, pTop, 1, -1);;

        self.left = pLeft;
        self.right = pRight;
        self.bottom = pBottom;
        self.top = pTop;

        GLfloat gridWidth = self.right - self.left;
        GLfloat gridHeight = self.top - self.bottom;
        GLfloat halfWidth = gridWidth / 2;
        GLfloat halfHeight = gridHeight / 2;


        // Create the vertices for each point of the grid
        float cellSize = 8.f;

        CGSize screenSize = [UIApplication currentSize];
        numRows = screenSize.height / cellSize;
        numCols = screenSize.width / cellSize;
        int verticesPerRow = numCols + 1;


        int verticesPerCell = 4;
        int numVertices = numRows * numCols * verticesPerCell;
        GLKVector2 *vertices = malloc(sizeof(GLKVector2) * numVertices);
        int vertexIndex;

        // Note use of <= as there is 1 more vertex row/col than numRows/numCols
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= numRows; rowIndex++) {

            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex <= numCols; colIndex++) {

                vertexIndex = (verticesPerRow * rowIndex) + colIndex;
                vertices[vertexIndex] = GLKVector2Make((cellSize * colIndex) - halfWidth, (cellSize * rowIndex) - halfHeight);
            }
        }

        // Create vertexIndices array which colours and vertices arrays wil be based on

        int triangleVerticesPerCell = 6; // Define 2 triangles per cell = 2 x 3 vertices
        numTriangleVertices = numRows * numCols * triangleVerticesPerCell;
        NSLog(@"numTriangleVertices %i", numTriangleVertices);
        //        numTriangleVertices = 6;

        int *vertexIndices = malloc(sizeof(int) * numTriangleVertices);
        int i = 0;

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numRows; rowIndex++) {

            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < numCols; colIndex++) {

                vertexIndex = (numCols * rowIndex) + colIndex + rowIndex;

                vertexIndices[i++] = vertexIndex;
                vertexIndices[i++] = vertexIndex + 1;
                vertexIndices[i++] = vertexIndex + verticesPerRow + 1;
                vertexIndices[i++] = vertexIndex;
                vertexIndices[i++] = vertexIndex + verticesPerRow + 1;
                vertexIndices[i++] = vertexIndex + verticesPerRow;
            }
        }


        // grid vertices
        //        int numTriangleVertices = 1 * triangleVerticesPerCell; // 1 cell
        triangleVertices = malloc(sizeof(GLKVector2) * numTriangleVertices);
        triangleColours = malloc(sizeof(GLKVector4) * numTriangleVertices);

        // Sets all values of array to 0
        //        memset(triangleVertices,0,sizeof(GLKVector2)*numVertices);

        GLKVector4 currColour;

        for (i = 0; i < numTriangleVertices; i++) {

            // Give a new colour to every new set of 6 vertices
            if(!(i % 6)) {

                currColour = GLKVector4Make(1.0 * arc4random_uniform(101)/100,
                                            1.0 * arc4random_uniform(101)/100,
                                            1.0 * arc4random_uniform(101)/100,
                                            1);
            }
            triangleColours[i] = currColour;

            // Next vertex
            triangleVertices[i] = vertices[vertexIndices[i]];
        }


        // Release memory later
        free(vertices);
        free(vertexIndices);

        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.02
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(timerUpdate:)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void) timerUpdate:(NSTimer*)timer {

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        int randomCellIndex = ((numRows * numCols)-1) * arc4random_uniform(10001)/10000;
        //        NSLog(@"randomCellIndex %i", randomCellIndex);
        // Loop through the random cell's vertices, setting thier colour
        GLKVector4 currColour = GLKVector4Make(1.0 * arc4random_uniform(101)/100,
                                               1.0 * arc4random_uniform(101)/100,
                                               1.0 * arc4random_uniform(101)/100,
                                               1);

        int startIndex = randomCellIndex * 6;

        for (int i = startIndex; i < startIndex + 6; i++) {

            triangleColours[i] = currColour;
        }
    }

}

-(void)render {
    //  NSLog(@"in EEScene's render");
    glClearColor(clearColor.r, clearColor.g, clearColor.b, clearColor.a);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    [effect prepareToDraw];

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2,
                          GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, triangleVertices);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 4,
                          GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, triangleColours);


    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numTriangleVertices);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This example from Apple looks like the answer :)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html